# Why using group by makes some id disappear

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

i was working in a machine learning project , and while i am extracting features i found that some of consumers LCLid disappear from the data set while i was grouping by the LCLid

Dataset: [SmartMeter Energy Consumption Data in London Households](https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/smartmeter-energy-use-data-in-london-households)

here is the original data set [image]

and here is the code that i used to extract some features

```py
LCLid=[]
for i in range(68):
    LCLid.append('MAC0000'+str(228+i))  

    consommation=data.groupby('LCLid')['KWH/hh'].sum()
    consommation_min=data.groupby('LCLid')['KWH/hh'].min()
    consommation_max=data.groupby('LCLid')['KWH/hh'].max()
    consommation_mean=data.groupby('LCLid')['KWH/hh'].mean()
    consommation_evening=data.groupby(['LCLid','period'])['KWH/hh'].mean()

#creation de dataframe
list_of_tuples = list(zip (LCLid, consommation, consommation_min, consommation_max, consommation_mean)) 
data2= pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples, columns = ['LCLid', 'Consumption', 'Consumption_min', 'Consumption_max', 'Consumption_mean'])
```

as you see after the execution of the code the dataset stopped in the LCLid 282 while iin the original one the dataset containes also the LCLid from 283 to 295

[image: as you see after the execution of the code the dataset stopped in the LCLid 282 while iin the original one the dataset containes also the LCLid from 283 to 295]

Comment: 1) please post your code as *text*, not images 2) this is a standard `pandas` question, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `jupyter-notebook` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (edited).

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thank you for your answer it helped me a lot , i'm new here so i don't know the checking feature so sorry and i have checked you answer now

Comment: Glad it helped. No problem, that's why I let you know.  I saw you had a few posted questions with no accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [low-carbon-london-data](https://data.london.gov.uk/download/smartmeter-energy-use-data-in-london-households/3527bf39-d93e-4071-8451-df2ade1ea4f2/Power-Networks-LCL-June2015(withAcornGps).zip) from [SmartMeter Energy Consumption Data in London Households](https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/smartmeter-energy-use-data-in-london-households)
- The issue is `LCLid` does not uniformly increment by `1`, from `MAC000228` to `MAC000295`.

```py
print(data.LCLid.unique())

array(['MAC000228', 'MAC000229', 'MAC000230', 'MAC000231', 'MAC000232',
       'MAC000233', 'MAC000234', 'MAC000235', 'MAC000237', 'MAC000238',
       'MAC000239', 'MAC000240', 'MAC000241', 'MAC000242', 'MAC000243',
       'MAC000244', 'MAC000245', 'MAC000246', 'MAC000248', 'MAC000249',
       'MAC000250', 'MAC000251', 'MAC000252', 'MAC000253', 'MAC000254',
       'MAC000255', 'MAC000256', 'MAC000258', 'MAC000260', 'MAC000262',
       'MAC000263', 'MAC000264', 'MAC000267', 'MAC000268', 'MAC000269',
       'MAC000270', 'MAC000271', 'MAC000272', 'MAC000273', 'MAC000274',
       'MAC000275', 'MAC000276', 'MAC000277', 'MAC000279', 'MAC000280',
       'MAC000281', 'MAC000282', 'MAC000283', 'MAC000284', 'MAC000285',
       'MAC000287', 'MAC000289', 'MAC000291', 'MAC000294', 'MAC000295'],
      dtype=object)

print(len(data.LCLid.unique()))

>>> 55
```

### To resolve the issue

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Power-Networks-LCL-June2015(withAcornGps)v2.csv')

# determine the rows needed for the MAC000228 - MAC000295
df[df.LCLid == 'MAC000228'].iloc[0, :]  # first row of 228
df[df.LCLid == 'MAC000295'].iloc[-1, :]  # last row of 295

# create a dataframe with the desired data
data = df[['LCLid', 'DateTime', 'KWH/hh (per half hour) ']].iloc[6989700:9032044, :].copy()

# fix the data
data.DateTime = pd.to_datetime(data.DateTime)
data.rename(columns={'KWH/hh (per half hour) ': 'KWH/hh'}, inplace=True)
data['KWH/hh'] = data['KWH/hh'].str.replace('Null', 'NaN')
data['KWH/hh'].fillna(np.nan, inplace=True)
data['KWH/hh'] = data['KWH/hh'].astype('float')
data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# aggregate your functions
agg_data = data.groupby('LCLid')['KWH/hh'].agg(['sum', 'min', 'max', 'mean']).reset_index()


print(agg_data)
```

#### `agg_data`

```py
        LCLid           sum    min    max      mean
0   MAC000228   5761.288000  0.021  1.616  0.146356
1   MAC000229   6584.866999  0.008  3.294  0.167456
2   MAC000230   8911.154000  0.029  2.750  0.226384
3   MAC000231   3174.314000  0.000  1.437  0.080663
4   MAC000232   2083.042000  0.005  0.736  0.052946
5   MAC000233   2241.591000  0.000  3.137  0.056993
6   MAC000234   9700.328001  0.029  2.793  0.246646
7   MAC000235   8473.999003  0.011  3.632  0.223194
8   MAC000237  22263.294998  0.036  4.450  0.598299
9   MAC000238   7814.889998  0.016  2.835  0.198781
10  MAC000239   6113.029000  0.015  1.346  0.155481
11  MAC000240   7280.662000  0.000  3.146  0.222399
12  MAC000241   4181.169999  0.024  1.733  0.194963
13  MAC000242   1654.336000  0.000  1.481  0.042088
14  MAC000243  11057.366999  0.009  3.588  0.281989
15  MAC000244   5894.271000  0.005  1.884  0.149939
16  MAC000245  22788.699005  0.037  4.743  0.580087
17  MAC000246  13787.060005  0.014  3.516  0.351075
18  MAC000248  10192.239001  0.000  4.351  0.259536
19  MAC000249  24401.468995  0.148  5.242  0.893042
20  MAC000250   5850.003000  0.000  2.185  0.148999
21  MAC000251   8400.234000  0.035  3.505  0.213931
22  MAC000252  21748.489004  0.135  4.171  0.554978
23  MAC000253   9739.408999  0.009  1.714  0.248201
24  MAC000254   9351.614001  0.009  2.484  0.238209
25  MAC000255  14142.974002  0.097  3.305  0.360220
26  MAC000256  20398.665001  0.049  3.019  0.520680
27  MAC000258   6646.485998  0.017  2.319  0.169666
28  MAC000260   5952.563001  0.006  2.192  0.151952
29  MAC000262  13909.603999  0.000  2.878  0.355181
30  MAC000263   3753.997000  0.015  1.060  0.095863
31  MAC000264   7022.967000  0.020  0.910  0.179432
32  MAC000267   8797.094000  0.029  2.198  0.224898
33  MAC000268   3734.252001  0.000  1.599  0.095359
34  MAC000269   2395.232000  0.000  1.029  0.061167
35  MAC000270  15569.711002  0.131  2.249  0.397501
36  MAC000271   7244.860000  0.028  1.794  0.184974
37  MAC000272   8703.658998  0.034  3.295  0.222446
38  MAC000273   3622.199002  0.005  5.832  0.092587
39  MAC000274  28724.718997  0.032  3.927  0.734422
40  MAC000275   5564.004999  0.012  1.840  0.161290
41  MAC000276  11060.774001  0.000  1.709  0.315724
42  MAC000277   8446.528999  0.027  1.938  0.241075
43  MAC000279   3444.160999  0.016  1.846  0.098354
44  MAC000280  12595.780001  0.125  1.988  0.360436
45  MAC000281   6282.568000  0.024  1.433  0.179538
46  MAC000282   4457.989001  0.030  1.830  0.127444
47  MAC000283   5024.917000  0.011  2.671  0.143627
48  MAC000284   1293.503000  0.000  0.752  0.047975
49  MAC000285   2399.018000  0.006  0.931  0.068567
50  MAC000287   1407.290000  0.000  2.372  0.045253
51  MAC000289   4767.490999  0.000  2.287  0.136436
52  MAC000291  13456.678999  0.072  3.354  0.385060
53  MAC000294   9477.966000  0.053  2.438  0.271264
54  MAC000295   7750.128000  0.010  1.839  0.221774
```